# SwiftUI: Using enterFullScreenMode on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, fullscreen

I've been using `window.toggleFullScreen()` to present a full-screen window, but I've found that this won't work on an iPad being used as a separate display.  The app won't transition on this screen - just gets a beep without any error being presented in the debug window (would appreciate any insights about this first problem :)

Code snippet for this transition:

```
  window.collectionBehavior = [] 
  window.toggleFullScreen(self)
```

- Frame resizes are handled by the delegates

I'm now trying to use `window.contentView`?.enterFullScreenMode.

This transitions ok (even on the iPad) **but I am missing the menu and dock**.

Code below:

```
// AppDelegate
var window: NSWindow!

// applicationDidFinishLaunching()
window = NSWindow(contentRect: device.size, styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
self.window.delegate = self
let contentView = ContentViewv11().frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: .infinity)
window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(display).  ....etc

// initiated via menu item action:
let presOptions: NSApplication.PresentationOptions = [.autoHideMenuBar, .autoHideDock]
let optionsDictionary = [NSView.FullScreenModeOptionKey.fullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: presOptions]
window.contentView?.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.main!, withOptions: optionsDictionary)
window.contentView?.wantsLayer = true \\tried also with this line removed
```

I haven't seen an example where `contentView` is being used with the `enterFullScreenMode` method.  This is giving me a completely blank window apart from the app itself.  No hidden dock or menu bar.  Users of the app will need at least the menu bar.  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried some attempts using Swift 2 calling window.contentView?.enterFullScreenMode from within a Scene displaying a single Window.  This was worse, I just got a blank screen and the Mac was locked up.  Calling .exitFullScreenMode or even  .toggleFullScreen wouldn't bring it back.

I found the cause of my original problem with .toggleFullScreen, during the transition to full screen I was calling window.setFrame.  The call was coming from the delegate methods with resizing.  Using .setFrame during the transition worked fine on a normal monitor but not using sidecar with the iPad.  **Pausing the .setFrame until windowDidEnterFullScreen() delegate was called fixed the problem.**

It looks to me that .toggleFullScreen is the method to use with SwiftUI for the moment.